# Fortify audit workbench stoped working after Big Sur is update

Tags: fortify

I am using fortify audit workbench, and I have generated fpr file and when I try open it in fortify a window show operation in progress and keep like this

Nothing changed but updating Big Sur is [image of the error showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVtf7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I believe you'll have a better chance of getting a useful answer if you provide additional information.  Please indicate if this worked in the past, if you did anything differently when it worked and so on.  Also indicate how you have generated the file, what steps you took.  If we don't know what steps you took, it's hard to tell you which ones were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A decent workaround is to use the pdf report generator to turn your fpr into a pdf:

```
ReportGenerator -format pdf -f MyReport.pdf -source MyApp.fpr -showSuppressed -showHidden
```

Comment: I used this way after searching for a way on how to generate fortify report using command line, unfortunately this way cannot generate  customized reports. 

I need to know is there anyway to use fortify with the new update? 

Thanks Bob for replying